# Injective modules and split sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, modules

I'm having trouble working this "if and only if", could someone help me?

How to prove that an $R$-module $E$ is injective if and only if for every ideal $I$ of $R$ the short exact sequence $0 \to E \to B \to I \to 0$ splits ?

Comment: Probably you should replace "cinde" by "splits", for English.

Comment: `\to` creates function arrows.

Comment: This isn't true. If $R = \mathbb{Z}$, then every ideal $I$ of $R$ is free, so every sequence $0 \to R \to B \to I \to 0$ splits, but $R$ is not injective. What is true is that $E$ is injective if every sequence $0 \to E \to B \to R/I \to 0$ splits - see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/615376/50739